# Insert into temporary table query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I'm looking to optimise a query that takes an excessive amount of time to run (around 1.5 hours), and through looking at the execution plan one of the biggest drains seems to be inserting the data from the main query into a temporary table. When I insert the data into a temporary table there is the following process :

Process (cost %)

```
Compute Scalar (0%) <-- Stream Aggregate (0%) <-- Sort(0%) <-- Table Spool (eager spool) (10%)
```

Which makes sense, but what doesn't to me is that this appears 9 times?

I can include the query / index information if this would help, but the query itself is quite long and I don't want to make this question into an essay!

Thanks,
Davin.

**Edit to include query - sorry for the length!**

```
IF object_id('tempdb..#category') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #category
CREATE TABLE #category
(
contact_id NVARCHAR(255)
,donor_class NVARCHAR(255)
,payment_type NVARCHAR(255)
,donation_type NVARCHAR(255)
,approach_channel NVARCHAR(255)
,count1987 INT
,sum1987 DECIMAL(18,3)
,count1988 INT
,sum1988 DECIMAL(18,3)
,count1989 INT
,sum1989 DECIMAL(18,3)
,count1990 INT
,sum1990 DECIMAL(18,3)
,count1991 INT
,sum1991 DECIMAL(18,3)
,count1992 INT
,sum1992 DECIMAL(18,3)
,count1993 INT
,sum1993 DECIMAL(18,3)
,count1994 INT
,sum1994 DECIMAL(18,3)
,count1995 INT
,sum1995 DECIMAL(18,3)
,count1996 INT
,sum1996 DECIMAL(18,3)
,count1997 INT
,sum1997 DECIMAL(18,3)
,count1998 INT
,sum1998 DECIMAL(18,3)
,count1999 INT
,sum1999 DECIMAL(18,3)
,count2000 INT
,sum2000 DECIMAL(18,3)
,count2001 INT
,sum2001 DECIMAL(18,3)
,count2002 INT
,sum2002 DECIMAL(18,3)
,count2003 INT
,sum2003 DECIMAL(18,3)
,count2004 INT
,sum2004 DECIMAL(18,3)
,count2005 INT
,sum2005 DECIMAL(18,3)
,count2006 INT
,sum2006 DECIMAL(18,3)
,count2007 INT
,sum2007 DECIMAL(18,3)
,count2008 INT
,sum2008 DECIMAL(18,3)
,count2009 INT
,sum2009 DECIMAL(18,3)
,count2010 INT
,sum2010 DECIMAL(18,3)
,category05 NVARCHAR(255)
,category06 NVARCHAR(255)
,category07 NVARCHAR(255)
,category08 NVARCHAR(255)
,category09 NVARCHAR(255)
,category10 NVARCHAR(255)
,[1987] NVARCHAR(4)
,[1988] NVARCHAR(4)
,[1989] NVARCHAR(4)
,[1990] NVARCHAR(4)
,[1991] NVARCHAR(4)
,[1992] NVARCHAR(4)
,[1993] NVARCHAR(4)
,[1994] NVARCHAR(4)
,[1995] NVARCHAR(4)
,[1996] NVARCHAR(4)
,[1997] NVARCHAR(4)
,[1998] NVARCHAR(4)
,[1999] NVARCHAR(4)
,[2000] NVARCHAR(4)
,[2001] NVARCHAR(4)
,[2002] NVARCHAR(4)
,[2003] NVARCHAR(4)
,[2004] NVARCHAR(4)
,[2005] NVARCHAR(4)
,[2006] NVARCHAR(4)
,[2007] NVARCHAR(4)
,[2008] NVARCHAR(4)
,[2009] NVARCHAR(4)
,[2010] NVARCHAR(4)
)
CREATE INDEX #idx_category ON #category (contact_id)

;WITH complete_finances as
(
(
SELECT
don.supporter_id AS contact_id
,don.id AS gift_id
,YEAR(don.date_received) AS calendar_year
,YEAR(don.date_received) - CASE WHEN MONTH(don.date_received) < 4 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS financial_year
,don.date_received AS date_received
,don.event_id AS event_id
,SUM(CASE   WHEN don.gift_aid_status <> 4 THEN don.value_gross * ((dfa.percentage) / 100)
            WHEN don.gift_aid_status = 4 AND don.value_net > don.value_gross
            AND don.value_net <> 0       THEN don.value_net  * ((dfa.percentage) / 100)
            ELSE don.value_gross  * ((dfa.percentage) / 100)
            END
        )   AS donation_value
,(CASE  WHEN don.payment_method IN (1, 2, 10, 11, 12, 200000, 200001, 200002, 200003, 200004, 200007, 200008, 200009 --single payments
                                            ,7,13,14) -- single payment refunds
                    THEN 'single'
        WHEN don.payment_method IN (3,4,5,9,200006)
                     THEN 'regular'
        ELSE 'other' END) AS type1
,CASE WHEN dfa.fund_id IN --all emergency funds
    (
    select f.id
    FROM _audit a
    INNER JOIN _fund f ON a.article_id = f.id
    WHERE a.entity_name = 'Fund'
    AND a.Changes LIKE 
    '%finance_code2%OldValue>3%'
    UNION
    select 
    id 
    FROM _fund
    WHERE (finance_code2 LIKE '3%'
    OR finance_code2 LIKE '9%')
    AND finance_code2 IS NOT NULL
    ) THEN 'Emergency' else 'Non-emergency' end as type2
FROM donation don WITH (nolock)
INNER JOIN donation_fund_allocation dfa WITH (nolock) ON dfa.donation_id = don.id
WHERE don.supporter_id IS NOT NULL
AND don.status = 4 -- posted donations only
AND don.value_gross <> 0 -- to include refunds as well
GROUP BY don.supporter_id
,don.id
,don.date_received
,don.event_id
,don.payment_method
,dfa.fund_id
)
UNION ALL
(
SELECT
caw.contact_id AS contact_id
,caw.id AS gift_id
,YEAR(caw.bank_date) AS calendar_year
,YEAR(caw.bank_date) - CASE WHEN MONTH(caw.bank_date) < 4 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS financial_year
,caw.bank_date AS date_received
,caw.event AS event_id
,(CASE      WHEN  caw.gift_aid_status <> 4 THEN caw.amount_exc_gift_aid 
            WHEN  caw.gift_aid_status = 4   THEN amount_inc_gift_aid
            END
        )   AS donation_value
,'CAW gift' AS type1
,'Non-emergency' AS type2
FROM gifts caw WITH (nolock)
WHERE caw.contact_id IS NOT NULL
AND caw.amount_exc_gift_aid <> 0
)
)
,category AS
(
SELECT
cmf.contact_id AS contact_id
,lfu.description AS donor_class
,ISNULL(cmf.type1,'Total') AS payment_type
,ISNULL(lac.description, 'Total') AS approach_channel
--,ISNULL(CASE  WHEN type1 = 'CAW gift' THEN 'CAW Gift'
--      WHEN type1 =  'Single'  THEN 'Non CAW gift'
--      WHEN type1 =  'Regular' THEN 'Non CAW gift'
--      WHEN type1 =  'Other'   THEN 'Non CAW gift'
--      END,'Total') AS payment_type2
,ISNULL(cmf.type2,'Total') AS donation_type
,SUM(CASE WHEN cmf.financial_year = '1987' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)                   AS count1987
,SUM(CASE WHEN cmf.financial_year = '1988' THEN cmf.donation_value ELSE 0 END)  AS sum1987
,SUM(CASE WHEN cmf.financial_year = '1988' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)               AS count1988
,SUM(CASE WHEN cmf.financial_year = '1988' THEN cmf.donation_value ELSE 0 END)  AS sum1988
,SUM(CASE WHEN cmf.financial_year = '1989' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)               AS count1989
,SUM(CASE WHEN cmf.financial_year = '1989' THEN cmf.donation_value ELSE 0 END)  AS sum1989
,SUM(CASE WHEN cmf.financial_year = '1990' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)               AS count1990
,SUM(CASE WHEN cmf.financial_year = '1990' THEN cmf.donation_value ELSE 0 END)  AS sum1990
,SUM(CASE WHEN cmf.financial_year = '1991' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)               AS count1991
,SUM(CASE WHEN cmf.financial_year = '1991' THEN cmf.donation_value ELSE 0 END)  AS sum1991
,SUM(CASE WHEN cmf.financial_year = '1992' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)               AS count1992
,SUM(CASE WHEN cmf.financial_year = '1992' THEN cmf.donation_value ELSE 0 END)  AS sum1992
,SUM(CASE WHEN cmf.financial_year = '1993' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)               AS count1993
,SUM(CASE WHEN cmf.financial_year = '1993' THEN cmf.donation_value ELSE 0 END)  AS sum1993
,SUM(CASE WHEN cmf.financial_year = '1994' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)               AS count1994
,SUM(CASE WHEN cmf.financial_year = '1994' THEN cmf.donation_value ELSE 0 END)  AS sum1994
,SUM(CASE WHEN cmf.financial_year = '1995' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)               AS count1995
,SUM(CASE WHEN cmf.financial_year = '1995' THEN cmf.donation_value ELSE 0 END)  AS sum1995
,SUM(CASE WHEN cmf.financial_year = '1996' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)               AS count1996
,SUM(CASE WHEN cmf.financial_year = '1996' THEN cmf.donation_value ELSE 0 END)  AS sum1996
,SUM(CASE WHEN cmf.financial_year = '1997' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)               AS count1997
,SUM(CASE WHEN cmf.financial_year = '1997' THEN cmf.donation_value ELSE 0 END)  AS sum1997
,SUM(CASE WHEN cmf.financial_year = '1998' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)               AS count1998
,SUM(CASE WHEN cmf.financial_year = '1998' THEN cmf.donation_value ELSE 0 END)  AS sum1998
,SUM(CASE WHEN cmf.financial_year = '1999' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)               AS count1999
,SUM(CASE WHEN cmf.financial_year = '1999' THEN cmf.donation_value ELSE 0 END)  AS sum1999
,SUM(CASE WHEN cmf.financial_year = '2000' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)               AS count2000
,SUM(CASE WHEN cmf.financial_year = '2000' THEN cmf.donation_value ELSE 0 END)  AS sum2000
,SUM(CASE WHEN cmf.financial_year = '2001' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)               AS count2001
,SUM(CASE WHEN cmf.financial_year = '2001' THEN cmf.donation_value ELSE 0 END)  AS sum2001
,SUM(CASE WHEN cmf.financial_year = '2002' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)               AS count2002
,SUM(CASE WHEN cmf.financial_year = '2002' THEN cmf.donation_value ELSE 0 END)  AS sum2002
,SUM(CASE WHEN cmf.financial_year = '2003' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)               AS count2003
,SUM(CASE WHEN cmf.financial_year = '2003' THEN cmf.donation_value ELSE 0 END)  AS sum2003
,SUM(CASE WHEN cmf.financial_year = '2004' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)               AS count2004
,SUM(CASE WHEN cmf.financial_year = '2004' THEN cmf.donation_value ELSE 0 END)  AS sum2004
,SUM(CASE WHEN cmf.financial_year = '2005' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)               AS count2005
,SUM(CASE WHEN cmf.financial_year = '2005' THEN cmf.donation_value ELSE 0 END)  AS sum2005
,SUM(CASE WHEN cmf.financial_year = '2006' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)               AS count2006
,SUM(CASE WHEN cmf.financial_year = '2006' THEN cmf.donation_value ELSE 0 END)  AS sum2006
,SUM(CASE WHEN cmf.financial_year = '2007' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)               AS count2007
,SUM(CASE WHEN cmf.financial_year = '2007' THEN cmf.donation_value ELSE 0 END)  AS sum2007
,SUM(CASE WHEN cmf.financial_year = '2008' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)               AS count2008
,SUM(CASE WHEN cmf.financial_year = '2008' THEN cmf.donation_value ELSE 0 END)  AS sum2008
,SUM(CASE WHEN cmf.financial_year = '2009' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)               AS count2009
,SUM(CASE WHEN cmf.financial_year = '2009' THEN cmf.donation_value ELSE 0 END)  AS sum2009
,SUM(CASE WHEN cmf.financial_year = '2010' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)               AS count2010
,SUM(CASE WHEN cmf.financial_year = '2010' THEN cmf.donation_value ELSE 0 END)  AS sum2010
FROM complete_finances cmf
INNER JOIN contact con WITH (nolock) ON con.id = cmf.contact_id
INNER JOIN [l_function] lfu WITH (nolock) ON lfu.code = con.class
LEFT OUTER JOIN event eve with (nolock) on eve.id = cmf.event_id
INNER JOIN [l_approach channel] lac WITH (nolock) ON lac.code = eve.class
WHERE cmf.contact_id IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY 
cmf.contact_id
,cmf.type1
,cmf.type2
,lfu.description
,lac.description
WITH CUBE
)
INSERT INTO #category
SELECT
contact_id
,donor_class
,payment_type
,donation_type
,approach_channel
,count1987
,sum1987
,count1988
,sum1988
,count1989
,sum1989
,count1990
,sum1990
,count1991
,sum1991
,count1992
,sum1992
,count1993
,sum1993
,count1994
,sum1994
,count1995
,sum1995
,count1996
,sum1996
,count1997
,sum1997
,count1998
,sum1998
,count1999
,sum1999
,count2000
,sum2000
,count2001
,sum2001
,count2002
,sum2002
,count2003
,sum2003
,count2004
,sum2004
,count2005
,sum2005
,count2006
,sum2006
,count2007
,sum2007
,count2008
,sum2008
,count2009
,sum2009
,count2010
,sum2010
,CASE   WHEN count2005 > 0 AND count1987+count1988+count1989+count1990+count1991
            +count1992+count1993+count1994+count1995+count1996
            +count1997+count1998+count1999+count2000+count2001
            +count2002+count2003+count2004 = 0 
            THEN 'New donor'
        WHEN count2005 > 0 AND count2004 = 0 AND
            count1987+count1988+count1989+count1990+count1991
            +count1992+count1993+count1994+count1995+count1996
            +count1997+count1998+count1999+count2000+count2001
            +count2002+count2003 > 0 
            THEN 'Reactivated donor'
        WHEN count2005 > 0 AND count2004 > 0 AND count2003 > 0
            AND count2002 > 0 AND count2001 > 0
            THEN '5+yrs consecutive'
        WHEN count2005 > 0 AND count2004 > 0 AND count2003 > 0
            AND count2002 > 0
            THEN '4yrs consecutive'
        WHEN count2005 > 0 AND count2004 > 0 AND count2003 > 0
            THEN '3yrs consecutive'
        WHEN count2005 > 0 AND count2004 > 0
            THEN '2yrs consecutive'
        WHEN count2005 = 0 AND count1987+count1988+count1989+count1990+count1991
            +count1992+count1993+count1994+count1995+count1996
            +count1997+count1998+count1999+count2000+count2001
            +count2002+count2003+count2004 > 0 
            THEN 'Lapsed Donor'
        WHEN    count1987+count1988+count1989+count1990+count1991
            +count1992+count1993+count1994+count1995+count1996
            +count1997+count1998+count1999+count2000+count2001
            +count2002+count2003+count2004+count2005 = 0 
            THEN 'Non donor'
END AS category05
,CASE   WHEN count2006 > 0 AND count1987+count1988+count1989+count1990+count1991
            +count1992+count1993+count1994+count1995+count1996
            +count1997+count1998+count1999+count2000+count2001
            +count2002+count2003+count2004+count2005 = 0 
            THEN 'New donor'
        WHEN count2006 > 0 AND count2005 = 0 AND
            count1987+count1988+count1989+count1990+count1991
            +count1992+count1993+count1994+count1995+count1996
            +count1997+count1998+count1999+count2000+count2001
            +count2002+count2003+count2004 > 0 
            THEN 'Reactivated donor'
        WHEN count2006 > 0 AND count2005 > 0 AND count2004 > 0
            AND count2003 > 0 AND count2002 > 0
            THEN '5+yrs consecutive'
        WHEN count2006 > 0 AND count2005 > 0 AND count2004 > 0 
            AND count2003 > 0
            THEN '4yrs consecutive'
        WHEN count2006 > 0 AND count2005 > 0 AND count2004 > 0
            THEN '3yrs consecutive'
        WHEN count2006 > 0 AND count2005 > 0
            THEN '2yrs consecutive'
        WHEN count2006 = 0 AND count1987+count1988+count1989+count1990+count1991
            +count1992+count1993+count1994+count1995+count1996
            +count1997+count1998+count1999+count2000+count2001
            +count2002+count2003+count2004+count2005 > 0 
            THEN 'Lapsed Donor'
        WHEN    count1987+count1988+count1989+count1990+count1991
            +count1992+count1993+count1994+count1995+count1996
            +count1997+count1998+count1999+count2000+count2001
            +count2002+count2003+count2004+count2005+count2006 = 0 
            THEN 'Non donor'
END AS category06
,CASE   WHEN count2007 > 0 AND count1987+count1988+count1989+count1990+count1991
            +count1992+count1993+count1994+count1995+count1996
            +count1997+count1998+count1999+count2000+count2001
            +count2002+count2003+count2004+count2005+count2006 = 0 
            THEN 'New donor'
        WHEN count2007 > 0 AND count2006 = 0 AND
            count1987+count1988+count1989+count1990+count1991
            +count1992+count1993+count1994+count1995+count1996
            +count1997+count1998+count1999+count2000+count2001
            +count2002+count2003+count2004+count2005 > 0 
            THEN 'Reactivated donor'
        WHEN count2007 > 0 AND count2006 > 0 AND count2005 > 0
            AND count2004 > 0 AND count2003 > 0
            THEN '5+yrs consecutive'
        WHEN count2007 > 0 AND count2006 > 0 AND count2005 > 0 
            AND count2004 > 0
            THEN '4yrs consecutive'
        WHEN count2007 > 0 AND count2006 > 0 AND count2005 > 0
            THEN '3yrs consecutive'
        WHEN count2007 > 0 AND count2006 > 0
            THEN '2yrs consecutive'
        WHEN count2007 = 0 AND count1987+count1988+count1989+count1990+count1991
            +count1992+count1993+count1994+count1995+count1996
            +count1997+count1998+count1999+count2000+count2001
            +count2002+count2003+count2004+count2005+count2006 > 0 
            THEN 'Lapsed Donor'
        WHEN    count1987+count1988+count1989+count1990+count1991
            +count1992+count1993+count1994+count1995+count1996
            +count1997+count1998+count1999+count2000+count2001
            +count2002+count2003+count2004+count2005+count2006+count2007 = 0 
            THEN 'Non donor'
END AS category07
,CASE   WHEN count2008 > 0 AND count1987+count1988+count1989+count1990+count1991
            +count1992+count1993+count1994+count1995+count1996
            +count1997+count1998+count1999+count2000+count2001
            +count2002+count2003+count2004+count2005+count2006+count2007 = 0 
            THEN 'New donor'
        WHEN count2008 > 0 AND count2007 = 0 AND
            count1987+count1988+count1989+count1990+count1991
            +count1992+count1993+count1994+count1995+count1996
            +count1997+count1998+count1999+count2000+count2001
            +count2002+count2003+count2004+count2005+count2006 > 0 
            THEN 'Reactivated donor'
        WHEN count2008 > 0 AND count2007 > 0 AND count2006 > 0
            AND count2005 > 0 AND count2004 > 0
            THEN '5+yrs consecutive'
        WHEN count2008 > 0 AND count2007 > 0 AND count2006 > 0 
            AND count2005 > 0
            THEN '4yrs consecutive'
        WHEN count2008 > 0 AND count2007 > 0 AND count2006 > 0
            THEN '3yrs consecutive'
        WHEN count2008 > 0 AND count2007 > 0
            THEN '2yrs consecutive'
        WHEN count2008 = 0 AND count1987+count1988+count1989+count1990+count1991
            +count1992+count1993+count1994+count1995+count1996
            +count1997+count1998+count1999+count2000+count2001
            +count2002+count2003+count2004+count2005+count2006+count2007 > 0 
            THEN 'Lapsed Donor'
        WHEN    count1987+count1988+count1989+count1990+count1991
            +count1992+count1993+count1994+count1995+count1996
            +count1997+count1998+count1999+count2000+count2001
            +count2002+count2003+count2004+count2005+count2006+count2007+count2008 = 0 
            THEN 'Non donor'
END AS category08
,CASE   WHEN count2009 > 0 AND count1987+count1988+count1989+count1990+count1991
            +count1992+count1993+count1994+count1995+count1996
            +count1997+count1998+count1999+count2000+count2001
            +count2002+count2003+count2004+count2005+count2006+count2007+count2008 = 0 
            THEN 'New donor'
        WHEN count2009 > 0 AND count2008 = 0 AND
            count1987+count1988+count1989+count1990+count1991
            +count1992+count1993+count1994+count1995+count1996
            +count1997+count1998+count1999+count2000+count2001
            +count2002+count2003+count2004+count2005+count2006+count2007 > 0 
            THEN 'Reactivated donor'
        WHEN count2009 > 0 AND count2008 > 0 AND count2007 > 0
            AND count2006 > 0 AND count2005 > 0
            THEN '5+yrs consecutive'
        WHEN count2009 > 0 AND count2008 > 0 AND count2007 > 0 
            AND count2006 > 0
            THEN '4yrs consecutive'
        WHEN count2009 > 0 AND count2008 > 0 AND count2007 > 0
            THEN '3yrs consecutive'
        WHEN count2009 > 0 AND count2008 > 0
            THEN '2yrs consecutive'
        WHEN count2009 = 0 AND count1987+count1988+count1989+count1990+count1991
            +count1992+count1993+count1994+count1995+count1996
            +count1997+count1998+count1999+count2000+count2001
            +count2002+count2003+count2004+count2005+count2006+count2007+count2008 > 0 
            THEN 'Lapsed Donor'
        WHEN    count1987+count1988+count1989+count1990+count1991
            +count1992+count1993+count1994+count1995+count1996
            +count1997+count1998+count1999+count2000+count2001
            +count2002+count2003+count2004+count2005+count2006+count2007+count2008+count2009 = 0 
            THEN 'Non donor'
END AS category09
,CASE   WHEN count2010 > 0 AND count1987+count1988+count1989+count1990+count1991
            +count1992+count1993+count1994+count1995+count1996
            +count1997+count1998+count1999+count2000+count2001
            +count2002+count2003+count2004+count2005+count2006+count2007+count2008+count2009 = 0 
            THEN 'New donor'
        WHEN count2010 > 0 AND count2009 = 0 AND
            count1987+count1988+count1989+count1990+count1991
            +count1992+count1993+count1994+count1995+count1996
            +count1997+count1998+count1999+count2000+count2001
            +count2002+count2003+count2004+count2005+count2006+count2007+count2008 > 0 
            THEN 'Reactivated donor'
        WHEN count2010 > 0 AND count2009 > 0 AND count2008 > 0
            AND count2007 > 0 AND count2006 > 0
            THEN '5+yrs consecutive'
        WHEN count2010 > 0 AND count2009 > 0 AND count2008 > 0 
            AND count2007 > 0
            THEN '4yrs consecutive'
        WHEN count2010 > 0 AND count2009 > 0 AND count2008 > 0
            THEN '3yrs consecutive'
        WHEN count2010 > 0 AND count2009 > 0
            THEN '2yrs consecutive'
        WHEN count2010 = 0 AND count1987+count1988+count1989+count1990+count1991
            +count1992+count1993+count1994+count1995+count1996
            +count1997+count1998+count1999+count2000+count2001
            +count2002+count2003+count2004+count2005+count2006+count2007+count2008+count2009 > 0 
            THEN 'Lapsed Donor'
        WHEN    count1987+count1988+count1989+count1990+count1991
            +count1992+count1993+count1994+count1995+count1996
            +count1997+count1998+count1999+count2000+count2001
            +count2002+count2003+count2004+count2005+count2006+count2007+count2008+count2009+count2010 = 0 
            THEN 'Non donor'
END AS category10
,CASE WHEN count1987 > 0 THEN 1987 END AS [1987]
,CASE WHEN count1988 > 0 THEN 1988 END AS [1988]
,CASE WHEN count1989 > 0 THEN 1989 END AS [1989]
,CASE WHEN count1990 > 0 THEN 1990 END AS [1990]
,CASE WHEN count1991 > 0 THEN 1991 END AS [1991]
,CASE WHEN count1992 > 0 THEN 1992 END AS [1992]
,CASE WHEN count1993 > 0 THEN 1993 END AS [1993]
,CASE WHEN count1994 > 0 THEN 1994 END AS [1994]
,CASE WHEN count1995 > 0 THEN 1995 END AS [1995]
,CASE WHEN count1996 > 0 THEN 1996 END AS [1996]
,CASE WHEN count1997 > 0 THEN 1997 END AS [1997]
,CASE WHEN count1998 > 0 THEN 1998 END AS [1998]
,CASE WHEN count1999 > 0 THEN 1999 END AS [1999]
,CASE WHEN count2000 > 0 THEN 2000 END AS [2000]
,CASE WHEN count2001 > 0 THEN 2001 END AS [2001]
,CASE WHEN count2002 > 0 THEN 2002 END AS [2002]
,CASE WHEN count2003 > 0 THEN 2003 END AS [2003]
,CASE WHEN count2004 > 0 THEN 2004 END AS [2004]
,CASE WHEN count2005 > 0 THEN 2005 END AS [2005]
,CASE WHEN count2006 > 0 THEN 2006 END AS [2006]
,CASE WHEN count2007 > 0 THEN 2007 END AS [2007]
,CASE WHEN count2008 > 0 THEN 2008 END AS [2008]
,CASE WHEN count2009 > 0 THEN 2009 END AS [2009]
,CASE WHEN count2010 > 0 THEN 2010 END AS [2010]
FROM category
WHERE 
contact_id IS NOT NULL
AND donor_class IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY contact_id
```

Comment: Yes, please post the full query along with the execution plan "text" and or XML.

Comment: What happens if you remove the table insertion from the query - just select the data? Are there any bad query plan estimations - i.e. points where the estimated number of rows and the actual number of rows differ vastly?

Comment: @tim the query takes around 30 minutes less to run when the insert into #table clause is removed, and in terms of bad query plans there are a few (the largest one being the intial clustered index scan on my primary table (donation), where the actual rows = 12,491,509 and the estimated is 193,940

Comment: @john - I am unable to post the execution plan (text or xml) as the number of characters is too large for one post. Is there any other information that would be useful (i.e. indexes?)

Comment: @Davin: Woah that is one nasty big query :-) It looks as though you are attempting to create an aggregate report of all of your financial data? Typically a job for the Datawarehouse. This will be tricky to assist you with without getting our hands dirty, which table schemas and test data will be needed for.

Comment: @Davin - Can you post the actual execution plan XML up to a third party service if it is too long for SO? (e.g. pastebin or similar)

Comment: @John - yeah that's pretty much what I'm looking to do, I will post some sample data as an answer to see if that helps

Comment: @martin - pastebin script here http://pastebin.com/us3ic5Z2 hopefully it's legible!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**sample data as no room in question!**

Main table information:

```
Create table #donation
(
contact_id NVARCHAR(255)
,id UNIQUEIDENTIFIER
,date_received DATETIME
,event_id NVARCHAR(255)
,value_gross DECIMAL(18,3)
,value_net DECIMAL(18,3)
,giftaid_status NVARCHAR(50)
,payment_method NVARCHAR(50) -- 3 = regular, 1 = single
)

INSERT INTO #donation VALUES 
('18EC3CD2-3065-4FF4-BE40-000004228590',    'CEDB5C00-DB78-4D70-B222-892DCAD361E6', '2008-02-12 00:00:00.000',  'AA9237FC-E9E0-48D4-BF2C-62DDCDA7E874', 15.00,  15.00,  1,  3)
('18EC3CD2-3065-4FF4-BE40-000004228590',    '45FB0841-BD82-47F2-B66F-473CE196B9E0', '2010-09-08 00:00:00.000',  'AA9237FC-E9E0-48D4-BF2C-62DDCDA7E874', 15.00,  15.00,  1,  3)
('18EC3CD2-3065-4FF4-BE40-000004228590',    'A27451B9-7542-4F61-A38F-EB202AD24CC5', '2010-03-09 00:00:00.000',  'AA9237FC-E9E0-48D4-BF2C-62DDCDA7E874', 15.00,  15.00,  1,  3)
('18EC3CD2-3065-4FF4-BE40-000004228590',    '8F9E143C-4E35-4C9B-A385-A86F20D8EDA4', '2008-06-06 00:00:00.000',  'AA9237FC-E9E0-48D4-BF2C-62DDCDA7E874', 15.00,  15.00,  1,  3)
('18EC3CD2-3065-4FF4-BE40-000004228590',    '47E91479-DAC6-4485-9C66-5970EA236CB0', '2009-07-10 00:00:00.000',  'AA9237FC-E9E0-48D4-BF2C-62DDCDA7E874', 15.00,  15.00,  1,  3)
('18EC3CD2-3065-4FF4-BE40-000004228590',    '5A8DED80-C7A7-477D-9E3C-5C4E147B89D3', '2009-04-08 00:00:00.000',  'AA9237FC-E9E0-48D4-BF2C-62DDCDA7E874', 15.00,  15.00,  1,  3)
('18EC3CD2-3065-4FF4-BE40-000004228590',    'CD45A6B2-1204-495C-8C4F-27DFECF689CB', '2009-05-08 00:00:00.000',  'AA9237FC-E9E0-48D4-BF2C-62DDCDA7E874', 15.00,  15.00,  1,  3)
('18EC3CD2-3065-4FF4-BE40-000004228590',    'E9C8C820-ECB7-4649-B27A-B84CD6029111', '2005-06-08 00:00:00.000',  '34AE7B04-279F-476E-B040-78BA727E4370', 10.00,  12.82,  4,  3)

CREATE TABLE #gifts
(
contact_id NVARCHAR(255)
,bank_date DATETIME
,id UNIQUEIDENTIFIER
,event_id NVARCHAR(255)
,giftaid_status INT
,amount_exc_giftaid DECIMAL(18,3)
,amount_inc_giftaid DECIMAL(18,3)
)

INSERT INTO #gifts VALUES
('18EC3CD2-3065-4FF4-BE40-000004228590','2006-05-31 00:00:00.000','A000BBCA-2C1D-4C53-8724-0E65498A7B21','97DAEE33-260A-46ED-8A14-201924BD057D',1,10.00,12.82)
('18EC3CD2-3065-4FF4-BE40-000004228590','2002-05-31 00:00:00.000','F81A2690-C096-4BE9-8DD5-1670896323FF','F9F06373-38BC-4567-9F8A-EEB4434524BA',1,10.00,12.82)
```

Additional tables: --data no really important here, but these are linked to the #donation table to determine if a donation is an emergency one or not (everything in the #gift table is assumed NOT to be an emergency)

```
CREATE TABLE #FUND
(
donation_id NVARCHAR(255)
,fund_id NVARCHAR(255)
,finance_code NVARCHAR(10)
,finance_code2 NVARCHAR(10)
)

CREATE TABLE #audit
(
entity_name NVARCHAR(255)
,changes NVARCHAR(5000)
)
```

CREATE TABLE #donation_fund
(donation_id NVARCHAR(255)
,fund_id NVARCHAR(255)
)

The #fund table is used to determine if the donation in the #donation table is an emergency or not - whether or not the fund id is an emergency one is determined by data in the #audit table.

To determine if the #donation is an emergency the following script snipped is used:

```
CASE WHEN #donation_fund.fund_id IN --all emergency funds
    (
    select f.id
    FROM _audit a
    INNER JOIN _fund f ON a.article_id = f.id
    WHERE a.entity_name = 'Fund'
    AND a.Changes LIKE 
    '%finance_code2%OldValue>3%'
    UNION
    select 
    id 
    FROM _fund
    WHERE (finance_code2 LIKE '3%'
    OR finance_code2 LIKE '9%')
    AND finance_code2 IS NOT NULL
    ) THEN 'Emergency' else 'Non-emergency' end as type2
```

Expected output (looks like this, actual figures will be different as result set below includes additional values):

```
contact_id  donor_class payment_type    donation_type   count2002   sum2002 count2003   sum2003 count2004   sum2004 count2005   sum2005 count2006   sum2006 count2007   sum2007 count2008   sum2008 count2009   sum2009 count2010   sum2010 category05  category06  category07  category08  category09  category10  1987    1988    1989    1990    1991    1992    1993    1994    1995    1996    1997    1998    1999    2000    2001    2002    2003    2004    2005    2006    2007    2008    2009    2010
18EC3CD2-3065-4FF4-BE40-000004228590    Unrestricted    gift    Non-emergency   1   10  0   0   0   0   0   0   1   10  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   Lapsed Donor    Reactivated donor   Lapsed Donor    Lapsed Donor    Lapsed Donor    Lapsed Donor    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    2002    NULL    NULL    NULL    2006    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
18EC3CD2-3065-4FF4-BE40-000004228590    Unrestricted    regular Non-emergency   0   0   1   12.82   2   25.64   12  151.022 12  224.359 12  180 12  180 12  180 8   120 3yrs consecutive    4yrs consecutive    5+yrs consecutive   5+yrs consecutive   5+yrs consecutive   5+yrs consecutive   NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    2003    2004    2005    2006    2007    2008    2009    2010
18EC3CD2-3065-4FF4-BE40-000004228590    Unrestricted    single  Non-emergency   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   19.231  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   New donor   Lapsed Donor    Lapsed Donor    Lapsed Donor    Lapsed Donor    Lapsed Donor    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    2005    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
18EC3CD2-3065-4FF4-BE40-000004228590    Unrestricted    Total   Non-emergency   1   10  1   12.82   2   25.64   13  170.253 13  234.359 12  180 12  180 12  180 8   120 4yrs consecutive    5+yrs consecutive   5+yrs consecutive   5+yrs consecutive   5+yrs consecutive   5+yrs consecutive   NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    2002    2003    2004    2005    2006    2007    2008    2009    2010
18EC3CD2-3065-4FF4-BE40-000004228590    Unrestricted    gift    Total   1   10  0   0   0   0   0   0   1   10  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   Lapsed Donor    Reactivated donor   Lapsed Donor    Lapsed Donor    Lapsed Donor    Lapsed Donor    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    2002    NULL    NULL    NULL    2006    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
18EC3CD2-3065-4FF4-BE40-000004228590    Unrestricted    regular Total   0   0   1   12.82   2   25.64   12  151.022 12  224.359 12  180 12  180 12  180 8   120 3yrs consecutive    4yrs consecutive    5+yrs consecutive   5+yrs consecutive   5+yrs consecutive   5+yrs consecutive   NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    2003    2004    2005    2006    2007    2008    2009    2010
18EC3CD2-3065-4FF4-BE40-000004228590    Unrestricted    single  Total   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   19.231  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   New donor   Lapsed Donor    Lapsed Donor    Lapsed Donor    Lapsed Donor    Lapsed Donor    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    2005    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
18EC3CD2-3065-4FF4-BE40-000004228590    Unrestricted    Total   Total   1   10  1   12.82   2   25.64   13  170.253 13  234.359 12  180 12  180 12  180 8   120 4yrs consecutive    5+yrs consecutive   5+yrs consecutive   5+yrs consecutive   5+yrs consecutive   5+yrs consecutive   NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    2002    2003    2004    2005    2006    2007    2008    2009    2010
```

Answer (score 2):

One minor suggestion in the mean time, you may find that you are better off creating the index on your temporary table after you have inserted the data into it, as doing so should improve the insertion speed. Creating it before hand means that the index must be modified for each and every record that you insert into the temp table.

Comment: tried this and unfortunately it doesn't seem to have made much of a difference :(

Answer (score 1):

I would investigate rewriting your query using a crosstab query ([PIVOT command in Sql Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410.aspx)). This is like a GROUP BY statement, except that it puts the aggregate values into columns rather than rows, which is what you're doing. It may take a little time to get your head round it but the effort will be worth it, you won't have all that copy-and-paste code, and it should run faster.

Comment: I have looked into this, but struggled to get my head around how to do the group by and not double up counts in the aggregation - should make a bit more sense once I've posted up some sample data