# optimal concatenation across rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I am looking to optimise a concatenation across multiple rows, and having read some similar questions am familiar with using STUFF + XML path etc. However, when I apply these to my query it usually times out when applying to the 9 million rows or so rows I have

What I'm looking for is a more efficient way of translating this:

```
create table #fruit
(
Contact_id NVARCHAR(50)
,fruit_type NVARCHAR(50)
,[2005_orders] int
,[2006_orders] int
,[2007_orders] int
,[2008_orders] int
,[2009_orders] int
)
INSERT INTO #fruit VALUES ('id001','banana',1,3,0,25,4)
INSERT INTO #fruit VALUES ('id001','apple',0,7,19,1,0)
INSERT INTO #fruit VALUES ('id001','orange',0,0,0,9,0)
INSERT INTO #fruit VALUES ('id001','strawberry',1,1,1,1,4)
INSERT INTO #fruit VALUES ('id001','grapes',0,3,0,0,0)
INSERT INTO #fruit VALUES ('id001','lemon',1,1,1,0,0)
```

Into this:

```
CREATE TABLE #results
(
contact_id NVARCHAR(255)
,fruit_type NVARCHAR(50)
,[2005_orders] int
,[2006_orders] int
,[2007_orders] int
,[2008_orders] int
,[2009_orders] int
,combination2005 NVARCHAR(500)
,combination2006 NVARCHAR(500)
,combination2007 NVARCHAR(500)
,combination2008 NVARCHAR(500)
,combination2009 NVARCHAR(500)
)
INSERT INTO #results VALUES ('id001','banana',1,3,0,25,4,'banana + strawberry + lemon','banana + apple + strawberry + grapes + lemon','apple + strawberry + lemon','banana + apple + orange + strawberry','banana + strawberry')
INSERT INTO #results VALUES ('id001','apple',0,7,19,1,0,'banana + strawberry + lemon','banana + apple + strawberry + grapes + lemon','apple + strawberry + lemon','banana + apple + orange + strawberry','banana + strawberry')
INSERT INTO #results VALUES ('id001','orange',0,0,0,9,0,'banana + strawberry + lemon','banana + apple + strawberry + grapes + lemon','apple + strawberry + lemon','banana + apple + orange + strawberry','banana + strawberry')
INSERT INTO #results VALUES ('id001','strawberry',1,1,1,1,4,'banana + strawberry + lemon','banana + apple + strawberry + grapes + lemon','apple + strawberry + lemon','banana + apple + orange + strawberry','banana + strawberry')
INSERT INTO #results VALUES ('id001','grapes',0,3,0,0,0,'banana + strawberry + lemon','banana + apple + strawberry + grapes + lemon','apple + strawberry + lemon','banana + apple + orange + strawberry','banana + strawberry')
INSERT INTO #results VALUES ('id001','lemon',1,1,1,0,0,'banana + strawberry + lemon','banana + apple + strawberry + grapes + lemon','apple + strawberry + lemon','banana + apple + orange + strawberry','banana + strawberry')
```

Where the key things to factor in are that I want a row per fruit type per contact (as this table will be used elsewhere) and that I only want a fruit to make it into the combination type if the count is greater than 0.

It might be that this isn't ever going to be very efficient given the number of rows I'm dealing with, but if there's any chance I can append this information onto my table that would be great :)

**Methods tried**

Method 1)

```
SELECT *
,STUFF(
(SELECT ' ' + fruit_type
FROM #fruit fr2
WHERE fr.contact_id = fr2.contact_id
AND 2005_orders > 0
order by contact_id,fruit_type
FOR XML path ('')
)
,1,1,''
) AS combination
FROM #fruit fr
```

Method 2)

```
SELECT *
,ISNULL((MAX(CASE WHEN fruit_type = 'banana' AND 2005_orders > 0 THEN 'banana ' END) OVER (PARTITION BY contact_id)),'')+
ISNULL((MAX(CASE WHEN fruit_type = 'apple' AND 2005_orders > 0 THEN 'apple ' END) OVER (PARTITION BY contact_id)),'')+
ISNULL((MAX(CASE WHEN fruit_type = 'orange' AND 2005_orders > 0 THEN 'orange' END) OVER (PARTITION BY contact_id)),'')+
ISNULL((MAX(CASE WHEN fruit_type = 'strawberry' AND 2005_orders > 0 THEN 'strawberry ' END) OVER (PARTITION BY contact_id)),'')+
ISNULL((MAX(CASE WHEN fruit_type = 'grapes' AND 2005_orders > 0 THEN 'grapes ' END) OVER (PARTITION BY contact_id)),'')+
ISNULL((MAX(CASE WHEN fruit_type = 'lemon' AND 2005_orders > 0 THEN 'lemon ' END) OVER (PARTITION BY contact_id)),'')+
AS combination05
FROM #fruit fr
```

-- which is then repeated for years 2006-2009 (which I know is hideously inefficient!)

Comment: What have you already tried? What's the timeout period?

Comment: @Ed :Methods included - timeout is around 2 hours (as far as I am aware)

Comment: Is this a report table generated from other normalized data?

Comment: @Kevpie Yes - this table is created from about 6 other tables which are all normalized

Comment: @Ed - the code to create the actual table is a bit of a monster, and is something I'm trying to improve, but thought it would be good to break this down into smaller steps! Full code can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4312965/insert-into-temporary-table-query

Comment: Do you have an index on `contact_id,fruit_type,2005_orders`?

Comment: @Martin - as it stands only on contact_id, as this table is used elsewhere and this was the most important thing to index - if I were to index the other columns that would mean around an extra dozen indexes, which I thought would be too many?

Comment: Are those the only 6 fruit types?

Comment: @kevpie yes - the number is fixed at six, so it can be hard coded if that helps!

Comment: Why does #results have a single fruit_type and then combinations of fruit types concatenated together?  It seems like you need a new table to hold the combinations as they aggregate the fruit_types together for a contact_id?

Comment: @kevpie - the reason is that I would like a main table to hold enough information to be able to query off - so that if someone wants to look at all people who only bought bananas + apples in 2005 can, as well as the totals of each type per year

Comment: Do you want the #results table to have fruit_type in it? And then presumably only combos with banana for the record that has fruit_type = banana.

Comment: @enth I want to have all fruit types for all contacts (whether or not there has ever been a purchase of it), and for each contact to have the combination of fruits for each year fixed, so that whether looking at row 'banana' for id001 or row 'apple' the output for 2005 will be  'banana + strawberry + lemon'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The performance issue with both of your methods is going to be the subquery. Try this strategy to break it apart and avoid subqueries.

You don't need to use outer joins if you are guaranteed to have records for each contact_id/fruit_type combo.

Index on contact_id should vastly improve performance.

```
SELECT
 f.*
 , combination2005 = 
     CASE WHEN b.[2005_orders] = 0 OR b.[2005_orders] IS NULL THEN '' ELSE 'banana + ' END
     + CASE WHEN a.[2005_orders] = 0 OR a.[2005_orders] IS NULL THEN '' ELSE 'apple + ' END
     + CASE WHEN o.[2005_orders] = 0 OR o.[2005_orders] IS NULL THEN '' ELSE 'orange + ' END
     + CASE WHEN s.[2005_orders] = 0 OR s.[2005_orders] IS NULL THEN '' ELSE 'strawberry + ' END
  , combination2006 = 
     CASE WHEN b.[2006_orders] = 0 OR b.[2006_orders] IS NULL THEN '' ELSE 'banana + ' END
     + CASE WHEN a.[2006_orders] = 0 OR a.[2006_orders] IS NULL THEN '' ELSE 'apple + ' END
     + CASE WHEN o.[2006_orders] = 0 OR o.[2006_orders] IS NULL THEN '' ELSE 'orange + ' END
     + CASE WHEN s.[2006_orders] = 0 OR s.[2006_orders] IS NULL THEN '' ELSE 'strawberry + ' END
FROM
 #fruit f
LEFT OUTER JOIN
 ( SELECT * FROM #fruit WHERE fruit_type = 'banana' ) b
ON
  f.contact_id = b.contact_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN
 ( SELECT * FROM #fruit WHERE fruit_type = 'apple' ) a
ON
  f.contact_id = a.contact_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN
 ( SELECT * FROM #fruit WHERE fruit_type = 'orange' ) o
ON
  f.contact_id = o.contact_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN
 ( SELECT * FROM #fruit WHERE fruit_type = 'strawberry' ) s
ON
  f.contact_id = s.contact_id
```

and don't use "SELECT *", I'm just being lazy.

I should add that if you don't expect every contact_id has a record for every fruit_type (thus you need to use outer joins here), then the case expressions should also test for null in addition to zero. (Added that above)

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't seem to rerturn the values I am looking for - instead of the combinationxxxx being fixed for all rows per contact_id, it seems to vary according to the row, so if the row is showing the values for bananas, the combination is only treated as bananas - this happens whether I do a LEFT OUTER or an INNER join.

Comment: I've had a chance to actually run this and I've made some minor edits so it actually runs (doh!). It returns fixed combinations for all rows.

Comment: Thanks for this - in my data this actually runs quite a lot slower vs method 2 above, but it's good to know of another way of approaching this

Comment: Ok, I'm out of ideas. That sure doesn't sound right. A join should outperform a correlated subquery. You definitely want indexes for that join to work quickly. In the above example, an index on contact_id would do wonders. And if your server doesn't have the resources (especially memory) then it's going to be slow no matter what as it has to page out to disk. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

It may not be appropriate/possible in your environment, but given that these figures relate to the past, have you considered pre-generating the concatenated string per contact per year into a table, using whatever method you currently have, and joining that to your results?

You might have to use a scheduled job to maintain the string for the current year, but it seems unlikely that the data for 2005-9 is going to change.

Comment: Unfortunately this data is only a subset of what I have- my actual data does include current ranges which naturally change frequently. Also, past data does seem to change quite a lot, and so this would need to be a bit more dynamic than just pasting a concatenated string...

Comment: This could be even be an int used as a bitmask for all of the permutations of the 6 fruit.  A lookup table or function to provide the string.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the timeout can be traced to the amount of redundant data you are calculating.  When I looked at your samples it seems the list of fruits are calculated for each row in the table.  I have take a different approach which might help.

I used the select below to place the fruit name in place of the sales value.

```
SELECT 
contact_id
,substring([fruit_type],1,cast(CAST([2005_orders] as bit)as int)*50) AS [2005_fruit]
,substring([fruit_type],1,cast(CAST([2006_orders] as bit)as int)*50) AS [2006_fruit]
,substring([fruit_type],1,cast(CAST([2007_orders] as bit)as int)*50) AS [2007_fruit]
,substring([fruit_type],1,cast(CAST([2008_orders] as bit)as int)*50) AS [2008_fruit]
,substring([fruit_type],1,cast(CAST([2009_orders] as bit)as int)*50) AS [2009_fruit]
from #fruit

contact_id                                         2005_fruit                                         2006_fruit                                         2007_fruit                                         2008_fruit                                         2009_fruit
-------------------------------------------------- -------------------------------------------------- -------------------------------------------------- -------------------------------------------------- -------------------------------------------------- --------------------------------------------------
id001                                              banana                                             banana                                                                                                banana                                             banana
id001                                                                                                 apple                                              apple                                              apple                                              
id001                                                                                                                                                                                                       orange                                             
id001                                              strawberry                                         strawberry                                         strawberry                                         strawberry                                         strawberry
id001                                                                                                 grapes                                                                                                                                                   
id001                                              lemon                                              lemon                                              lemon
```

I believe the next step is to pivot the output of the select shown concatenating the fruit.  The target should be a table which could be joined to the origional fruit table.  If needed the table could be hardened into the results table except there is way to much redundant data which will kill you IO.